# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Document.GetElementsByName'

Tags: html, vbscript

I have the below code and after some debugging i've hit a brick wall. whilst debugging it throws up the error

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Document.GetElementsByName'

when executing the submit button it loads up the spreadsheet but because of the error doesn't know what to write to it to then be able to follow through the actions.

Code is below

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<Html>
<Head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
Sub Divert ()
    Dim iRow
    Set objExcel = CreateObject ("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("G:\Bournemouth\CorporateShared\General Insurance\GI complaint Team\CRU Diverted\diverted.xlsx")
    objExcel.Application.Visible = True
    ObjWorkbook.Windows (1).Visible = True
    Set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets (1)
    XlSheet.Activate

    iRow = 1
    With objExcel
    Do while .Cells (iRow, 1).value <> ""
    .Cells (iRow, 1).activate
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop

    .Cells (iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("date2") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("date3") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("name1") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("acti") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 5).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("supwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 6).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("prowhi") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 7).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("trawha") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 8).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("hanwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 9).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("prowha") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 10).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("surwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 11).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("letwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 12).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("miwha") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 13).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("miwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 14).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("time1") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 15).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("desc1") (0).Value



    End With
    ObjWorkbook. Save
    ObjWorkbook. Close
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
</script>

<style type="text/css">
form    {

    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
    height: 450px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: inset 1px solid #333;
    }
button  {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: #09C;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1p solid #999;
    }

input.button:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #09C;
    }
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #09C;
    }

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
    hidefield();
    document.getElementById( 'div-' + name).style.display="block";
}


function hidefield() {
document.getElementById('div-1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-2').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-3').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-4').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-5').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-6').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-7').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div-8').style.display='none';
}
</script>   
</head>
<body onload="hidefield()">
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Diverted Time Sheet</legend>
<center>
Date:<br>
<input id="date" name="date2" maxlength="10" size="10">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
    document.getElementById('date').value = today;
    </script>   
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="date1" name="date3">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
    document.getElementById('date1').value = today;
    </script>
Name :<br>
<select name="name1" value="">
    <option value="James Dark">James Dark</option>
    <option value="Jane Dean">Jane Dean</option>
    <option value="Leanne Lambert">Leanne Lambert</option>
    <option value="Tracey Stratford">Tracey Stratford</option>
    <option value="Robert Macallan">Robert Macallan</option>
    <option value="Michael Mcdonald">Michael Mcdonald</option>
    <option value="Sarah Murphy">Sarah Murphy</option>
    <option value="Amanda Myatt">Amanda Myatt</option>
    <option value="Joanne Kerley">Joanne Kerley</option>
    <option value="Kay Land">Kay Land</option>
    <option value="John Dinsdale">John Dinsdale</option>
    <option value="Chris Baxter">Chris Baxter</option>
    <option value="Casey Sparkes">Casey Sparkes</option>
    <option value="James Purnell">James Purnell</option>
    <option value="Kate Bingham">Kate Bingham</option>
    <option value="Kevin Dix">Kevin Dix</option>
    <option value="Tyrone Moll">Tyrone Moll</option>
    <option value="Kate Bishop">Kate Bishop</option>
    <option value="Jason Gamble">Jason Gamble</option>
    <option value="Tony Parkinson">Tony Parkinson</option>
    <option value="Tom Seaman">Tom Seaman</option>
    <option value="Carolyn Lester">Carolyn Lester</option>
    <option value="Debbie Gray">Debbie Gray</option>
    <option value="Chris McCormack">Chris McCormack</option>
    <option value="Marion Greenaway">Marion Greenaway</option>
    <option value="Sarah White">Sarah White</option>
    <option value="Angela Manning">Angela Manning</option>
    <option value="Buffy Gammond">Buffy Gammond</option>
    <option value="Andy Holmes">Andy Holmes</option>
    <option value="Nathan Gatehouse">Nathan Gatehouse</option>
    <option value="Dan Bishop">Dan Bishop</option>
    <option value="Heather Townend">Heather Townend</option>
    <option value="Ben Krigers">Ben Krigers</option>
    <option value="Jacob Gibney">Jacob Gibney</option>
    <option value="Robert Mcleish">Robert Mcleish</option>
    <option value="Stuart Vidler">Stuart Vidler</option>
    <option value="Rebekah Coldwell">Rebekah Coldwell</option>
    <option value="Majid Ali">Majid Ali</option>
    <option value="Sharon Borg">Sharon Borg</option>
    <option value="Rich Hall">Rich Hall</option>
    <option value="Paul Dargan">Paul Dargan</option>
    <option value="Mel Davis">Mel Davis</option>
    <option value="Elaine Hawkins">Elaine Hawkins</option>
    <option value="Humma Khan">Humma Khan</option>
    <option value="Chris Jones">Chris Jones</option>
    <option value="Matt Tottle">Matt Tottle</option>
    <option value="Nathan Middleton">Nathan Middleton</option>
    <option value="Helen Wentland">Helen Wentland</option>
    <option value="Adriann Quintas">Adriann Quintas</option>
</select><br>
Activity :<br>
<select name="acti" value="" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="9">Worked hours</option>
    <option value="10">Overtime</option>
    <option value="11">Sickness</option>
    <option value="12">Unpaid leave</option>
    <option value="13">Compassionate leave</option>
    <option value="14">Holiday inc bank holidays</option>
    <option value="15">Team meetings</option>
    <option value="16">One to ones</option>
    <option value="17">One to one prep</option>
    <option value="18">Huddles</option>
    <option value="1">Supplier meetings</option>
    <option value="2">Product meetings</option>
    <option value="3">Training/coaching</option>
    <option value="4">Handling other peoples cases</option>
    <option value="5">Project work</option>
    <option value="6">Surgery time for GK</option>
    <option value="7">Letter checks and feedback</option>
    <option value="8">MI/Reporting/RCA</option>
</select><br>
<div id="div-1">Supplier meetings with :<br>
<select name="supwho" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Davies">Davies</option>
    <option value="Gelder">Gelder</option>
    <option value="Evander">Evander</option>
    <option value="Brittania Rescue">Brittania Rescue</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-2">Which product meeting :<br>
<select name="prowhi" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Home">Home</option>
    <option value="Motor">Motor</option>
    <option value="Legal">Legal</option>
    <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-3">What training/coaching :<br>
<select name="trawha" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Leon">Leon</option>
    <option value="Releases">Releases</option>
    <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
    <option value="Team leader">Team leader</option>
    <option value="Updates">Updates</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-4">Whos case handling :<br>
<select name="hanwho" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="James Dark">James Dark</option>
    <option value="Jane Dean">Jane Dean</option>
    <option value="Leanne Lambert">Leanne Lambert</option>
    <option value="Tracey Stratford">Tracey Stratford</option>
    <option value="Robert Macallan">Robert Macallan</option>
    <option value="Michael Mcdonald">Michael Mcdonald</option>
    <option value="Sarah Murphy">Sarah Murphy</option>
    <option value="Amanda Myatt">Amanda Myatt</option>
    <option value="Joanne Kerley">Joanne Kerley</option>
    <option value="Kay Land">Kay Land</option>
    <option value="John Dinsdale">John Dinsdale</option>
    <option value="Chris Baxter">Chris Baxter</option>
    <option value="Casey Sparkes">Casey Sparkes</option>
    <option value="James Purnell">James Purnell</option>
    <option value="Kate Bingham">Kate Bingham</option>
    <option value="Kevin Dix">Kevin Dix</option>
    <option value="Tyrone Moll">Tyrone Moll</option>
    <option value="Kate Bishop">Kate Bishop</option>
    <option value="Jason Gamble">Jason Gamble</option>
    <option value="Tony Parkinson">Tony Parkinson</option>
    <option value="Tom Seaman">Tom Seaman</option>
    <option value="Carolyn Lester">Carolyn Lester</option>
    <option value="Debbie Gray">Debbie Gray</option>
    <option value="Chris McCormack">Chris McCormack</option>
    <option value="Marion Greenaway">Marion Greenaway</option>
    <option value="Sarah White">Sarah White</option>
    <option value="Angela Manning">Angela Manning</option>
    <option value="Buffy Gammond">Buffy Gammond</option>
    <option value="Andy Holmes">Andy Holmes</option>
    <option value="Nathan Gatehouse">Nathan Gatehouse</option>
    <option value="Dan Bishop">Dan Bishop</option>
    <option value="Heather Townend">Heather Townend</option>
    <option value="Ben Krigers">Ben Krigers</option>
    <option value="Jacob Gibney">Jacob Gibney</option>
    <option value="Robert Mcleish">Robert Mcleish</option>
    <option value="Stuart Vidler">Stuart Vidler</option>
    <option value="Rebekah Coldwell">Rebekah Coldwell</option>
    <option value="Majid Ali">Majid Ali</option>
    <option value="Sharon Borg">Sharon Borg</option>
    <option value="Rich Hall">Rich Hall</option>
    <option value="Paul Dargan">Paul Dargan</option>
    <option value="Mel Davis">Mel Davis</option>
    <option value="Elaine Hawkins">Elaine Hawkins</option>
    <option value="Humma Khan">Humma Khan</option>
    <option value="Chris Jones">Chris Jones</option>
    <option value="Matt Tottle">Matt Tottle</option>
    <option value="Nathan Middleton">Nathan Middleton</option>
    <option value="Helen Wentland">Helen Wentland</option>
    <option value="Adriann Quintas">Adriann Quintas</option>
    <option value="Business area">Business area</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-5">What project work :<br>
<select name="prowha" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="FCA changes">FCA changes</option>
    <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
    <option value="RCA">RCA</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-6">Surgery time with who :<br>
<select name="surwho" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="James Dark">James Dark</option>
    <option value="Jane Dean">Jane Dean</option>
    <option value="Leanne Lambert">Leanne Lambert</option>
    <option value="Tracey Stratford">Tracey Stratford</option>
    <option value="Robert Macallan">Robert Macallan</option>
    <option value="Michael Mcdonald">Michael Mcdonald</option>
    <option value="Sarah Murphy">Sarah Murphy</option>
    <option value="Amanda Myatt">Amanda Myatt</option>
    <option value="Joanne Kerley">Joanne Kerley</option>
    <option value="Kay Land">Kay Land</option>
    <option value="John Dinsdale">John Dinsdale</option>
    <option value="Chris Baxter">Chris Baxter</option>
    <option value="Casey Sparkes">Casey Sparkes</option>
    <option value="James Purnell">James Purnell</option>
    <option value="Kate Bingham">Kate Bingham</option>
    <option value="Kevin Dix">Kevin Dix</option>
    <option value="Tyrone Moll">Tyrone Moll</option>
    <option value="Kate Bishop">Kate Bishop</option>
    <option value="Jason Gamble">Jason Gamble</option>
    <option value="Tony Parkinson">Tony Parkinson</option>
    <option value="Tom Seaman">Tom Seaman</option>
    <option value="Carolyn Lester">Carolyn Lester</option>
    <option value="Debbie Gray">Debbie Gray</option>
    <option value="Chris McCormack">Chris McCormack</option>
    <option value="Marion Greenaway">Marion Greenaway</option>
    <option value="Sarah White">Sarah White</option>
    <option value="Angela Manning">Angela Manning</option>
    <option value="Buffy Gammond">Buffy Gammond</option>
    <option value="Andy Holmes">Andy Holmes</option>
    <option value="Nathan Gatehouse">Nathan Gatehouse</option>
    <option value="Dan Bishop">Dan Bishop</option>
    <option value="Heather Townend">Heather Townend</option>
    <option value="Ben Krigers">Ben Krigers</option>
    <option value="Jacob Gibney">Jacob Gibney</option>
    <option value="Robert Mcleish">Robert Mcleish</option>
    <option value="Stuart Vidler">Stuart Vidler</option>
    <option value="Rebekah Coldwell">Rebekah Coldwell</option>
    <option value="Majid Ali">Majid Ali</option>
    <option value="Sharon Borg">Sharon Borg</option>
    <option value="Rich Hall">Rich Hall</option>
    <option value="Paul Dargan">Paul Dargan</option>
    <option value="Mel Davis">Mel Davis</option>
    <option value="Elaine Hawkins">Elaine Hawkins</option>
    <option value="Humma Khan">Humma Khan</option>
    <option value="Chris Jones">Chris Jones</option>
    <option value="Matt Tottle">Matt Tottle</option>
    <option value="Nathan Middleton">Nathan Middleton</option>
    <option value="Helen Wentland">Helen Wentland</option>
    <option value="Adriann Quintas">Adriann Quintas</option>
    <option value="Business area">Business area</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-7">Letter check for who :<br>
<select name="letwho" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="James Dark">James Dark</option>
    <option value="Jane Dean">Jane Dean</option>
    <option value="Leanne Lambert">Leanne Lambert</option>
    <option value="Tracey Stratford">Tracey Stratford</option>
    <option value="Robert Macallan">Robert Macallan</option>
    <option value="Michael Mcdonald">Michael Mcdonald</option>
    <option value="Sarah Murphy">Sarah Murphy</option>
    <option value="Amanda Myatt">Amanda Myatt</option>
    <option value="Joanne Kerley">Joanne Kerley</option>
    <option value="Kay Land">Kay Land</option>
    <option value="John Dinsdale">John Dinsdale</option>
    <option value="Chris Baxter">Chris Baxter</option>
    <option value="Casey Sparkes">Casey Sparkes</option>
    <option value="James Purnell">James Purnell</option>
    <option value="Kate Bingham">Kate Bingham</option>
    <option value="Kevin Dix">Kevin Dix</option>
    <option value="Tyrone Moll">Tyrone Moll</option>
    <option value="Kate Bishop">Kate Bishop</option>
    <option value="Jason Gamble">Jason Gamble</option>
    <option value="Tony Parkinson">Tony Parkinson</option>
    <option value="Tom Seaman">Tom Seaman</option>
    <option value="Carolyn Lester">Carolyn Lester</option>
    <option value="Debbie Gray">Debbie Gray</option>
    <option value="Chris McCormack">Chris McCormack</option>
    <option value="Marion Greenaway">Marion Greenaway</option>
    <option value="Sarah White">Sarah White</option>
    <option value="Angela Manning">Angela Manning</option>
    <option value="Buffy Gammond">Buffy Gammond</option>
    <option value="Andy Holmes">Andy Holmes</option>
    <option value="Nathan Gatehouse">Nathan Gatehouse</option>
    <option value="Dan Bishop">Dan Bishop</option>
    <option value="Heather Townend">Heather Townend</option>
    <option value="Ben Krigers">Ben Krigers</option>
    <option value="Jacob Gibney">Jacob Gibney</option>
    <option value="Robert Mcleish">Robert Mcleish</option>
    <option value="Stuart Vidler">Stuart Vidler</option>
    <option value="Rebekah Coldwell">Rebekah Coldwell</option>
    <option value="Majid Ali">Majid Ali</option>
    <option value="Sharon Borg">Sharon Borg</option>
    <option value="Rich Hall">Rich Hall</option>
    <option value="Paul Dargan">Paul Dargan</option>
    <option value="Mel Davis">Mel Davis</option>
    <option value="Elaine Hawkins">Elaine Hawkins</option>
    <option value="Humma Khan">Humma Khan</option>
    <option value="Chris Jones">Chris Jones</option>
    <option value="Matt Tottle">Matt Tottle</option>
    <option value="Nathan Middleton">Nathan Middleton</option>
    <option value="Helen Wentland">Helen Wentland</option>
    <option value="Adriann Quintas">Adriann Quintas</option>
    <option value="Business area">Business area</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-8">What MI/Reporting/RCA :<br>
<select name="miwha" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Nationwide">Nationwide</option>
    <option value="Daily Review">Daily Review</option>
    <option value="Adhoc">Adhoc</option>
</select><br>
Who requested MI/Reporting/RCA :<br>
<select name="miwho" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Chris Joy">Chris Joy</option>
    <option value="Nadine Ralph">Nadine Ralph</option>
    <option value="Darrel Minvalla">Darrel Minvalla</option>
    <option value="Amanda May">Amanda May</option>
    <option value="Treca Legg">Treca Legg</option>
    <option value="Business Area">Business Area</option>
</select><br></div>
<div id="div-9"></div><div id="div-10"></div><div id="div-11"></div><div id="div-12"></div><div id="div-13"></div><div id="div-14"></div><div id="div-15"></div><div id="div-16"></div><div id="div-17"></div><div id="div-18"></div>
Time in minutes :<br>
<input type="text" name="time1" Value="">
<br>
Description :<br>
<input type="text" name="desc1" Value=""><br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="Divert()" value="Submit"><br>
</center>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been working on this for some time and i am stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Its to write the actions that colleagues do during the day to a spreadsheet so that can be reviewed, its all on an internal network.

Thanks

Comment: This coding is working for me,What is your error explain in detail.

Comment: I currently click the submit button and it loads the spreadsheet up but stops there, it doesn't input the information from the form to the spreadsheet and save and close. It just comes up with the above mentioned error when debugging.

Comment: Are you running it from IE?

Comment: Yes , I ran it in IE

Comment: Thats strange then, i'm running in IE11 but have the coding in to take compatibility back to IE8 as it had issues without this